# downloading a CSV with wget

Tags: python, csv, wget

Hi i am newish to python, and working on modeling of the CV-19 outbreak in the UK.

Currently I am writting a program to automatically download the UK governments latest death statistics.

Here is my code so far:

```
import wget

url = "https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/downloads/csv/coronavirus-cases_latest.csv"#

wget.download(url, 'C:/Users/Moshe/Downloads/Covid_19_uk_timeseries.csv')
```

Running this in pycharm I get:

```
C:\Users\Moshe\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Moshe/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/Get_CV19_UK_stats.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Moshe/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/Get_CV19_UK_stats.py", line 6, in <module>
    wget.download(url, 'C:/Users/Moshe/Downloads/Covid_19_uk_timeseries.csv')
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 308: Permanent Redirect

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The file I am trying to get can be found on this page:
https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/?_ga=2.157835066.1251021075.1589887735-1783596499.1585566366

Why won't this work? and what do i need to change?

Comment: Why is the URL in your code different than the url in your post?

Comment: Please describe any errors you are seeing.

Comment: if people think wget is the wrong way to do this i am open to other options!

Comment: @jordanm its the page I found the csv on. I've edited my post to make this clearer.

Comment: @kenY-N I've added errors to the post

Comment: Your error is because the URL returns a redirect rather than the file. You need to update your code to handle the redirect. I recommend the "requests" library instead of wget, which is somewhat of the de-facto standard for making HTTP requests in python.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your output path is valid and writeable?

try

```
import wget
import os

output_dir = 'C:/Users/Moshe/Downloads'
output_file = 'Covid_19_uk_timeseries.csv'

assert os.path.exists(output_dir)

url = "https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/downloads/csv/coronavirus-cases_latest.csv"#

wget.download(url, out = os.path.join(output_dir,output_file))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have downloaded other files there with wget when i was writting it originally, so i think its fine.

Comment: I'm new to python so i may be getting this wrong. When i type in  "pip install os" to terminal i get this error:"
Collecting os

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for os
"

Comment: As a result i dont seem to be able to import it

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26171823)

Comment: @Abijah `os` is a standard library that comes with every version of Python, so you do not need to install it.

Comment: I thought it must not have been installed because I get an error.

Comment: C:\Users\Moshe\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Moshe/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/Get_CV19_UK_stats.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Moshe/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/Get_CV19_UK_stats.py", line 11, in <module>
    wget.download(url, out = os.path.join(output_dir,output_file))
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

Comment: I think it needs to use requests. I am now working out how to do that